# Jenkins on Windows SSL website wont initiate

Tags: ssl, jenkins, certificate, keystore, jks

**Windows 2012 R2**

**Jenkins on version 2.32.2**

Having issues getting Jenkins running with SSL certificate. Created the JKS, the certificate was issued from our Windows CA, chain and issuing certs imported. I have done a ton of certificate work and wont rule out a keystore issue but its unlikely.

Change the Jenkins.xml to:

```
<arguments>-Xrs -Xmx256m -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle -jar "%BASE%\jenkins.war" --httpPort=-1 --httpsPort=8443 --httpsKeyStore="%BASE%\secrets\jenkins.jks" --httpsKeyStorePassword=passwordmasked --webroot="%BASE%\war"</arguments>
```

Checked jenkins.err.log and dont see any errors, last line is always
INFO: Jenkins is fully up and running

When I try to access the site it just fails. Dosent look like it even attempts the TCP/SSL handshake. Running wireshark I dont see any HTTPs traffic initiated.

Not sure where to go from here. I could front end this in IIS or Apache but would like to keep it simple.

Comment: How did you create the cert and what error do you see? I've had issues with certificates generated with a weak diffie hellman.

Comment: e:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jre\bin>keytool -genkey -alias argonauta -keyalg
RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore Jenkins.jks -dname "CN=url.com,OU=IS
&T, O=ommit, L=New York, ST=New York, C=US" -ext SAN=dn
s:url.com

Comment: got it to work. I re-created the keystore again, same way, issued the cert the same way. I suspect that the original keystore something with the chain/cert itself or the private key was just off.

Comment: Does the browser say it couldn't connect to the server or throw a 4xx, or 5xx error? I've had issues with the signature being too short, which will be killed by Chrome by default and IE kills the command unless you modify the registry.